# How to automaticly change specific letter with something else

Tags: pdftex, packages

I have a problem with letter đ because everytime I write something in serbian latex document fails to compile this letter. Is there any package that can fix this or always change đ to dj when I compile it so I don't need to manually fix it every time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want the output of `đ` to be `dj`?

Comment: No i want đ to change to dj in original tex file so it can compile

Comment: đ  should work anyway, what error do you get?

Comment: l.15 ...monović. Svima se tema svidjela osim Anđ
                                                  i ko

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produc
Transcript written on D.log.

Comment: can you add the actual log file (not the terminal output) as a code block in your question

Comment: https://pastebin.com/a26rAysu

Comment: that paste is completely different it shows a log of a file with no error and 2 pages of pdf output.

Comment: you could put the full log of the first example I put in my answer into your question.

Comment: Your answer solved it. Using that package gives me no errors.

Comment: using fontenc changes the font (and means that you can get correct hyphenation for Serbian) but is not needed to parse đ  both those examples would produce identical looking output if you remove the fontenc line. But anyway glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}


abcđ 

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

If you need dj then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0111}{dj}
\begin{document}


abcđ 

\end{document}
```

producing

[image]